# Increment a for loop by 3 then by 1 using matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I am working on MATLAB code right now, and I want to increment `y` by 3 then by 1 and so on.

Here is the code if anyone could help, it would be appreciated.

```
for y=1:2:9
    for x=9:-1:1
        A(x,y)=1
        if x==1 && y~=9 
            %y=y+1
            for x= 1:9
                A(x,y)=1
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What is the exact issue you are having with you code?

Comment: what does *so on* mean? -1?

Answer (score 0):

You first make a vector of the indexes you want to visit and then loop over the vector.

```
idx = [1,2,5]; %and so on
for ct = 1:length(idx)
    A(x,y(idx(ct)))=1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a [predefined vector](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html#buhafti-3) or even matrix to be used in for loop; not necessary to use range index.

Answer (score -1):

I am not completely certain how your question is reflected in your code. However, if you want to alternately increment `y` with 1 and 3, I would make a standard for-loop and then update `y` inside. Something like:

```
n = 100;
for i = 1:n
    y = y + 2*mod(i,2)+1;
    display(y) %Do things
end
```